# Can't create directory in etc for hadoop?

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I am following [hadoop installation tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). It says that

> Unpack the downloaded Hadoop distribution. In the distribution, edit the file etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh to define some parameters as follows:

but when I open etc directory, I right-click to create a new directory inside. But "Create New Folder" option is disabled in context-menu. How can I create it?

Comment: a normal user doesn't have write access in `/etc` folder. you need root access for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because nautilus is not opened as root (superuser).
Try to launch it from root with sudo nautilus&. But know that everything that you will do from that will not be accessible for standard users. So do not create files in your home directory.

Comment: First, I misunderstood the instruction that there is another etc folder in downloaded hadoop package. Second I did not know about nautilus (yes I am so new [: ). Now I am OK. Thanks.